# Why String comparison "==" doesn't work? Python 3.6

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a function that takes a part number and then retrieves its product webpage link from this website: http://www.assmann-wsw.com

I am using the bs4 module to parse the webpage. 
The url follows this structure when doing a part number search:

"http://www.assmann-wsw.com/us/en/artikelfinder/?artnr=" + part_number + "&artnr-search=find+now#searchresults"

This line collects all part numbers in 'td' tag.

```
all_artnr = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'artnr'})
```

There are three scenarios when searching a part number:

(1). Part number doesn't exist

(2). Part number exists and it is not a substring of other part numbers.

(3). Part number exists and it is a substring of other part numbers.

Scenarios (1) and (2) are handled easily. In scenario 3, the website returns all product webpage of part numbers that contains the input part number as a substring.

I was thinking to compare the text of the td tag with the input part number. When they match, the product webpage is contained in that td tag.

Below is the code I have and its output. 
The last two outputs show a match, but the comparison returns false. 
Please help me understand what is happening here. Thank you.

```
import bs4
import requests


def get_pwp(pn):
    home_page = "http://www.assmann-wsw.com/"
    #url_p1_de = "http://www.assmann-wsw.com/wo/en/artikelfinder/?artnr="
    url_p1_us = "http://www.assmann-wsw.com/us/en/artikelfinder/?artnr="
    url_p2 = "&artnr-search=find+now#searchresults"

    search_url = url_p1_us + str(pn) + url_p2
    src = requests.get(search_url).content

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

    # product webpage
    pwp = ''
    all_artnr = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'artnr'})

    # Part number doesn't exist
    if len(all_artnr) == 0:
        pwp = '#NA'

    # Part number exists and it is not a substring of other part numbers.
    elif len(all_artnr) == 2 or len(all_artnr) == 1:
        pwp = home_page + all_artnr[0].find('a')['href']

    # Part number exists and it is a substring of other part numbers.
    else:
        for artnr in all_artnr:
            print(str(artnr.text), pn)
            print(str(artnr.text) == pn)

            if str(artnr.text) == str(pn):
                pwp = home_page + artnrfind('a')['href']
                break

    return pwp

pwp = get_pwp("A-MCSP-80300")
print(pwp)



Output:

A‑MCSP‑80300‑R A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300‑R A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300/B A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300/B A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300/G A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300/G A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300/R A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300/R A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300/Y A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300/Y A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300 A-MCSP-80300
False
A‑MCSP‑80300 A-MCSP-80300
False


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the strings are not the same, they just look that way when you print them.

The first contains "NON-BREAKING HYPHEN" which is represented as the unicode character `'\u2011'`. The second value contains an ASCII hypen ("HYPHEN-MINUS") character, `'\u002D'`.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> s1 = 'A‑MCSP‑80300'
>>> s2 = 'A-MCSP-80300'

>>> s1 == s2
False

>>> s1.encode('utf8')
b'A\xe2\x80\x91MCSP\xe2\x80\x9180300'

>>> s2.encode('utf8')
b'A-MCSP-80300'

>>> unicodedata.name(s1[1])
'NON-BREAKING HYPHEN'
>>> unicodedata.name(s2[1])
'HYPHEN-MINUS'
```

You could replace one with the other before comparing:

```
>>> s1.replace('\u2011', '-') == s2.replace('\u2011', '-')
True
```